# Sqlalchemy detect change in table

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

In a `thread` I would like to check for whenever a particular value in my `database` `table` changes. Something like this:

```
def my_background_thread():
while True:
    check_for_changes_to_database
    if change:
       do_something()
```

I'm using `mySQL` and `sqlalchemy`. Does `sqlalchemy` provide a way to do this?

Comment: Short answer; no. You *should* really think about storing such real-time data in [RethinkDB](http://rethinkdb.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[SQLAlchemy Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html)

do_something() can be registered as a listener of SQLAlchemy's 'set' event for 'changes' in the database.

eg.

```
listen('changes', 'set', do_something)
```